# python.ext No module named pip

Tags: python, cmd, python-3.6

After installation of pip, still i am getting below error

```
C:\Users\Admin>python -m pip install cx_Oracle
C:\Program Files\python-3.6.4-embed-win32\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Below are the version's setup in my PC.

```
C:\Users\Admin>python --version
    Python 3.6.4

    C:\Users\Admin>pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)

    C:\Users\Admin>path
    PATH=F:\app\praveenp\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;
    C:\Program Files\python-3.6.4-embed-win32;
    C:\Users\Admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Scripts;
```

can you please help me out. Agenda is to install cx_Oracle module.

Comment: Always use full paths or you are at the mercy of system configuration.

Comment: @ACatInLove what does it mean ? can you correct what is wrong in environment variables.

Comment: Filename can be enclosed with quotes. If the path has spaces they MUST be enclosed with quotes. `"C:\Users\MYFIRSTNAME MYSECONDNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python" "C:\folder\pip" Install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are working with different Python environment. "pip" is for Python 2. You need to install "pip3".

```
inquisitum@question ~
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14

inquisitum@question ~
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3

inquisitum@question ~
$ pip3 install cx_Oracle
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Downloading cx_Oracle-6.1.tar.gz (232kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 2.7MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: cx-Oracle
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cx-Oracle ... -
```